# Story about astronauts crashing on a planet inhabited by robots

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I read this SF story somewhere in 2000s. I believe it was in English but might have been a translation from the original work. It might have been a short story or a novella.

The story's core premise was about astronauts (crash?) landing on a planet that was inhabited solely by robots. I don't recall if it was a part of their mission or if they did it only to save their lives from hostile natives, the astronauts managed to create metallic disguises for themselves (from ship parts?).

some time later it was revealed that there

> actually were no robots, every robot was in fact a human who had disguised himself as a robot to blend in the society

that is all i remember. Can anyone help me identify the author and the story's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Stanislaw Lem's anthology work [*The Star Diaries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Diaries), more specifically the short story *The Eleventh Voyage*.

> By the way, Lem’s story ends with the protagonist’s discovery that the robot planet contains no real robots, but only human agents dressed up as robots, all sent in disguise to infiltrate the ranks of the Magnificans. Having betrayed their humanity, they all act like robots, and wage a fake war on humans. He sadly concludes that “only Man can be a bastard”.
>
> <sub><sup>[Body Issues — Human and Robotic](https://explore.scimednet.org/index.php/body-issues-human-and-robotic/)</sup></sub>